Having trouble using a local php script as a mailer for my Angular app
I'm having two problems here actually.
I have the following in my service:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmailService {

 private emailUrl = 'http://localhost/grandmascookieshoppe-ng/src/services/email-form.php'; 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  sendEmail(name: string, email: string, phone: string, message: string) {
    const data = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      phone: phone,
      message: message
    };
    return this.http.post(this.emailUrl, data);
  }
}

My first problem is that I can't really leave that localhost URL as such since I'll be uploading to a real site. I need a generic way to reference that file. However, anything other than the full-blown URL generates a 404. I guess I can sort of solve this by making the first portion of the URL controlled by a pair of variables that I swap out when I send it live. But I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution.
Second issue is that even like this, where it finds the file, I get a CORS error even though I added it in the headers:
...
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *';
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
...

I don't know if that one is simply since it's localhost or what, but I'd appreciate any input.
Thank you.

You can handle your problem 1 with different environments: for local you set localhost, and for prod the "real site" url. Have a look at the documentation from angular about different environments: https://v17.angular.io/guide/build

What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you struggling with setting the proper request URL, or with the CORS header? In both cases, sending an Access-Control-Origin-Header in an email is pretty strange if the browser already causes problems requesting the script itself in the first place - sending these headers through a mail won't even affect how the browser works

I get a CORS error even though I added it in the headers:...you've added the cors headers to the email, not to the php script's response...

If you get an error though, tell us what it says! There are lots of types of cors error

However, anything other than the full-blown URL generates a 404...that'll be because your php backend is on a different origin than the angular frontend. Therefore relative URLs won't work because they're not part of the same site.

Thank you all. I'll try modifying based on these comments and let you know how it went.

Instead of hardcoding the URL in your Angular service, you can use Angular's environment configurations to handle different URLs for development and production.
environment.ts
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  emailUrl: 'http://localhost/grandmascookieshoppe-ng/src/services/email-form.php'
};

environment.prod.ts
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  emailUrl: 'https://yourproductiondomain.com/path/to/email-form.php'
};

The CORS error usually occurs because the browser enforces the Same-Origin Policy, which prevents requests to a different domain or port unless the server allows it.
Add the CORS headers at the beginning of your PHP script:
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");

$email_from = 'example@example.com';
$email_to = 'recipient@example.com';
$email_subject = 'Subject';
$email_message = 'Message body';
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);


Heh, well good news and bad news. After making all these changes, I still had to put a copy of the email_form.php in the dist folder after the build to get it to be seen. The script seems to think it sent the mail successfully, but it never showed up.  Not even sure what to ask at this point.

Could this be an issue with Php's mailer? I know I've used this same script on a previous site and it worked fine then. But, it's clearly not now. :( Any thoughts of where to look next?

NVMD. It appears that somehow I missed reinstalling php and the mailer after a reinstall at some point. DOH! I'll go see if fixing all that up helps!
